# Calling formflow from LUIS in bot framework 4.0

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, formflow

I need to call the formflow from LUIS using bot framework 4.0. Is it possible to do? If anyone has done it before please share reference links.
Thanks,
Sheveta

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve here, but FormFlow has been deprecated from the core SDK as of v4.  It is however available via the Bot Builder Community project on GitHub over at https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet or via NuGet at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.FormFlow/

Comment: I think the `closest-match` similar to FormFlow will be Waterfall

Comment: I am trying to implement a form flow on any one of the LUIS intent.

Comment: I have multiple LUIS intents from which one of the intent will call the formflow. I have implemented the same in V3 but not sure how to do in v4

Answer (score 0):

FormFlows are removed from the Bot Framework SDK v4, they were an essential part of SDK v3 nonetheless.

**However if you want to mimic the functionality of FormFlows the closest you can get using purely SDK v4 is by using [Waterfall dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) which are like mini dialogs prompted at each step.**

And also like Gary said, you can use the [Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.FormFlow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.FormFlow/) nuget package for getting a [port](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.FormFlow/README.md) into SDK v4.

Comment: Thanks will try using them.